# Is there a base Shader class?

Tags: c#, shader, directx-11, sharpdx

I am currently writing an in-depth `DirectX-11` engine at work and am working on my shader sections. I can't seem to find a `class` that is common to all of the following:

```
VertexShader
PixelShader
GeometryShader
HullShader
DomainShader
ComputeShader
```

Is there a base level class that all of these types derive from or am I stuck with large chunks of code to handle each individually? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DirectX 11, each shader type is a distinct interface and the Direct3D functions you call using them need the specific type.

In most rendering cases, you'll only use a VS and PS anyhow.

There are a number of ways to create an abstraction for shaders. For example, in the *XNA Game Studio* class design, the `Effect` class wrapped up both a VS and a PS which you used with `Apply` (which in the abstraction could really be any shader stages needed for that rendering effect). See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2010/04/22/effect-api-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0/).

> Technically they are all derived from `ID3D11DeviceChild` but you need the distinct interface anyhow to use them.